# C++ - Passing data between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a thread pool consists of 4 threads: t1, t2, t3, and t4. They are running concurrently, but the input from t3 and t4 depends on output from t2. How should I implement message queue so that after t2 completes, it will send the output data to t3 and t4 for processing? I have tried to implement the message queue using locking mechanism, but it seems that the locking is quite expensive. Is there lock-free mechanism that pass data between threads?
I am using boost::thread in visual studio 2010.

Comment: Learn from following link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595760/c-communication-between-threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost has a lock-free queue: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/lockfree.html.

Comment: Hi Tomo, for my case both t3 and t4 need to get the output data from t2. So, I wonder who will dequeue the data from message queue? Should it be t2 cause we are not sure whether t3 or t4 will complete first? I mean whenever t2 enqueue new data, it will perform dequeue as well.

Comment: Yes, t2 should put its output into the queue. T3 and t4 should periodically check if there's anything in the queue to process. Assuming t3 and t4 do have other things to do. If not (i.e. their only job is to wait for t2's output and process it), forget about lock-free queues and just go with a locking solution. If the threads need to wait anyway, cost of locking should not be your concern.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider [tbb](/questions/tagged/tbb). It provides a wide range of parallel concepts including `concurrent_queue`, `concurrent_bounded_queue` (for waiting), `pipeline`, `flow::graph`. The first two are also available in [ppl](/questions/tagged/ppl) within MS VS 2010.

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks for replying! Cause my project currently uses boost lib, so I will focus more on boost. But I will take a look at TBB as well if I cannot find any solution. :))