# Multiplatform cross thread communication in C++14

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have C++14 program that uses thread for loading data from large files. I use `std::thread` and in method, data are loaded. However, after data are loaded I need to notify main thread (GUI, console...), that data are ready. How can I achieve this?

I have found this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16726/Cross-thread-calls-in-native-C, but it is Windows only. On Linux, I can use signals and interrruptions, but I dont think that is a good idea.

Is there any C++14 mechanism, that allows you wo call method XY on threadID and OS will schedule it?

Comment: try to read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595760/c-communication-between-threads

Comment: There are several ways for thread communication in std::thread.  A nice one that might fit is [std::promise](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise)

Comment: In Linux this has historically been done with pipes or shared memory. No need for C++14 features (AFAIK).

Comment: The problem with the question is that the thread communication should be based on how your system works, which we don't know.  What I do know is that standard c++ doesn't have functions in other threads.  You can adapt the code in the linked article to std::thread, but the destination thread would still be needing to wait for the function to be received, see the code `while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer: `promise` and `future`.

When you create your `std::thread`, create a `std::promise` object, and pass it to your thread. For example:

```
std::promise<void> promise_that_data_is_loaded;
auto loaded_future = promise_that_data_is_loaded.get_future();
std::thread t([&promise_that_data_is_loaded]()
{
    loadData();
    promise_that_data_is_loaded.set(); //set this after work is done
});
while(loaded_future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) != std::future_status::ready)
{
    //wait, or refresh GUI, or do other stuff, etc...
}
loaded_future.get();
t.join();
```

Note: I didn't compile this. This is off the top of my head.

With this example, you see that you pass a promise, that when `set()`, will tell another thread that it's ready.

When you create your thread, pass the data/class with a promise that should be set, and set it when you're done. This will tell your GUI when you're finished.

Comment: In this, I have to "wait" in while-loop. I dont want to do this. I wan to call method from thread and specify on which thread it should be executed

Comment: @MartinMickey This is just an example. In your real GUI program, you put that promise in the class that has the data to be analyzed, and you pull the future from it before executing the task, and finally you get the GUI to check the status of the future periodically until it's ready.

Comment: But I dont have there any periodic code... I must manually call "refresh" or something like that. Otherwise, methods are not executed from GUI and I dont have access to main update loop.

Comment: @MartinMickey ALL gui libraries are based on event loops and/or timers. I.e., you always have something periodically checking. This is how GUIs work. So you should get your gui to check the status either with a timer or something else. There's no magic that will give you a "signal" that your result is ready. I'm assuming here you're not using Qt with signals and slots, because that's a whole other story and this whole discussion won't apply. In that case you could use `QThread`, which supports signaling when ready (which will basically do what you have to do now manually).

Comment: your a bit edited code and it compiles, but dies with SIGABRT http://ideone.com/NcT1oH

Comment: @Sugar Because you didn't join... I joined now in my code. Here you go: http://ideone.com/mnpeij